# Numpy: array of indices based on array shape?

Tags: python, numpy

say I have a simple array:

```
a = np.zeros([3,3])
>>> [ 0 0 0 , 0 0 0 , 0 0 0 ]
```

Is there a utility function that would give me an array with the same dimensions that contains the "coordinates" of each point on `a`? So,

```
ia = np.indexer(a)
>>> [ (0,0) (0,1) (0,2), (1,0) (1,1) (1,2), (2,0) (2,1) (2,2) ]
```

? I basically want to vectorize an operation for which I am currently using np.ndenumerate, but it would be easier if the output of ndenumerate was in matrix form.

```
class GLWidget(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):
  target_array = None

  ...

  def paintGL(self):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    self.render()

  def render(self):
    if self.target_array is None:
      return

    starting_abs_point = -(np.array(self.target_array.shape)-1)/(2*np.max(self.target_array.shape))
    glTranslate(*starting_abs_point)
    last_rel_coords= np.zeros(3)

    for idx, value in np.ndenumerate(self.target_array): # vectorization target!
      rel_coords = np.array(idx)/np.max(self.target_array.shape)
      step = rel_coords-last_rel_coords
      last_rel_coords = rel_coords

      glTranslate(*step)
      glutWireCube(value/( np.max(self.target_array)*np.max(self.target_array.shape) ))

    glTranslate(*-(starting_abs_point+last_rel_coords))
```

Goal (it currently looks terrible because I can't get lighting and stuff going yet, but it's a learning exercise):
[image]

Comment: Normally you use `np.indices` to get an index grid, then you can use that grid, or zip or flatten it as appropriate.

Comment: Most probably, there is a better way to achieve what you actually want to do, and this better way does not involve creating this kind of array.  What is you actual goal?

Comment: I am using OpenGL to draw a matrix of random numbers between 0 and 1 as a 3D Hinton map. The value of each cell in the matrix is the dimension at that point, and the index represents the relative position.

I will edit to show my current code.

Comment: Since you are calling `glutWireCube()` in every loop iteration, I don't see how you would be able to vectorize this loop (unless this function supports operating on NumPy arrays).  That said, moving the call to `np.max(self.target_array)` out of the loop will speed things up, since you don't have to iterate over the whole array for every single element anymore.